# wrong wifi adapter detection

Tags: wireless, 22.04, firmware

I have a problem with my wifi adapter, firmware rtl8188EU which is included in ubuntu 22.04 natively. The problem is that ubuntu recognize it as rtl8188EUS. It hangs when i enter the wifi key. How can i set ubuntu to use rtl8188EU instead of rtl8188EUS ? I used a ppa with the right driver, but since a kernel update, it doesn't exists anymore. I would like that ubuntu's kernel use the right firmware.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Looks like those 2 use the same driver so you issue is likely something else. r8188eu do you have that blacklisted? Here is a method for building listed https://github.com/aircrack-ng/rtl8188eus